# Mutliply two rows using same categorical field SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

I apologize if the title is a bit vague, was not sure how to word it! Essentially in MS SQL Server 2008, I am trying to multiply a value by another value, with both values having the same common categorical field (but different value). This should be quite easy, but I cannot get the structure or syntax correct for the select statement. An example is best:

```
TableA
Year | Quarter | Name   | Parameter | Month1   | Month2  | ...Month12
2015 | Mar     | Jones  |    A      |   123.45 |  678.99 | ..
2015 | Mar     | Jones  |    B      |   33.45  |  444.99 | ..
2015 | Mar     | Jones  |    C      |   0.22   |  0.21   | ..
2015 | Mar     | Jones  |    D      |   0.01   |  0.05   | ..
2015 | Mar     | Smith  |    A      |   555.11 |  333.22 | ..
2015 | Mar     | Smith  |    B      |   222.11 |  101.31 | ..
2015 | Mar     | Smith  |    C      |   0.02   |  0.08   | ..
2015 | Mar     | Smith  |    D      |   0.09   |  0.21   | ..
```

In a temp table TableA, I am trying to multiply Month1 for Parameter A by Month1 for Parameter C for each name, and placing this new value in a new Month1 field in TableB.

TableB would have identical fields to TableA, except the Parameter field would contain new/different items (eg. X, Y.. as it is now a calculated field). I would do similarly for Month2, Month3.. etc to Month12. When writing the select query, I do not know whether to put a sub-query in the select statement using a where clause for each Parameter value, or place the sub-query in the 'from' list... Neither have worked for me!

Any help is much appreciated!
Thanks

Comment: can u add expected output data as well?

Answer (score 1):

Hope it is something like this you're looking for, but I must admit, this smells like structure re-design...

Just paste this into an empty query window and execute. Adapt to your needs...

```
DECLARE @tblA TABLE (Year INT, Quarter VARCHAR(3), Name VARCHAR(10),Parameter VARCHAR(1),Month1 DECIMAL(6,2), Month2 DECIMAL(6,2) /*further months*/);
INSERT INTO @tblA VALUES
 (2015,'Mar','Jones','A',123.45,678.99)
,(2015,'Mar','Jones','B',33.45,444.99)
,(2015,'Mar','Jones','C',0.22,0.21)
,(2015,'Mar','Jones','D',0.01,0.05)
,(2015,'Mar','Smith','A',555.11,333.22)
,(2015,'Mar','Smith','B',222.11,101.31)
,(2015,'Mar','Smith','C',0.02,0.08)
,(2015,'Mar','Smith','D',0.09,0.21)

SELECT * FROM @tblA;

DECLARE @tblB TABLE (Year INT, Quarter VARCHAR(3), Name VARCHAR(10),Parameter VARCHAR(1),Month1 DECIMAL(6,2), Month2 DECIMAL(6,2)/*further months*/);

WITH RowsWithA AS
(
    SELECT * FROM @tblA WHERE Parameter='A'
)
INSERT INTO @tblB
SELECT Year,Quarter,Name,'x',MonthsCalculated.*
FROM RowsWithA
CROSS APPLY
(
    SELECT RowsWithA.Month1 * (  SELECT x.Month1 
                                 FROM @tblA AS x 
                                 WHERE x.Year =RowsWithA.Year 
                                   AND x.Quarter=RowsWithA.Quarter 
                                   AND x.Name=RowsWithA.Name
                                   AND x.Parameter='C'
                              ) AS Month1
          ,RowsWithA.Month2 * (  SELECT x.Month2 
                                 FROM @tblA AS x 
                                 WHERE x.Year =RowsWithA.Year 
                                   AND x.Quarter=RowsWithA.Quarter 
                                   AND x.Name=RowsWithA.Name
                                   AND x.Parameter='C'
                              ) AS Month2
          /*further months*/
) AS MonthsCalculated;

SELECT * FROM @tblB
```